# VHDL writing std_logic_vector as a signed integer in file

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I wonder how to write a std_logic_vector as a signed integer in VHDL testbench?

Answer (score 2):

Using numeric_std:

```
signal test_in  : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal test_out : integer range -4 to 3;

test_out <= to_integer(signed(test_in));
```

Comment: Not sure a signed 3 bit vector will fit in an `integer range 0 to 7` will it?

Comment: Indeed.  I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to an integer (using the `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`, which means you need to know if your `std_logic_vector` is representing a signed or unsigned number.  [Ideally, you'd use the relevant type rather than the bag-of-bits that `std-logic_vector` is.](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/)

Converting to an integer is as straightforward as:

```
int_variable := to_integer(some_vector);
```

If you must stick to a `std_logic_vector` you'll have to tell the compiler whether it is unsigned or signed like this:

```
int_variable := to_integer(unsigned(some_vector));
```

or this:

```
int_variable := to_integer(signed(some_vector));
```

Then you can write you integer to the file as you normally would.